# Is there any memory consumption issue when we use static method EventLog.WriteEntry() ?

Tags: c#, event-log

Is there any memory leak/consumption problem when I use `EventLog.WriteEntry()` static method as compared to creating object of `EventLog` class and then call `WriteEntry()` method?

Comment: Don't know what motivated you to ask this question. I found it via a Google search after a report from a memory profiler showed that my program is "leaking" 32 bytes every time I use EventLog.WriteEntry().

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/services/monitoring/system/diagnosticts/EventLog.cs#e310f11e57f6a787) you can find the sources for the EventLog class (.NET 4.5.1).
As you can see, the static method instantiate a new EventLogInternal on each call.
The non-static one re-uses a field instantiated on the constructor.

That said, I think there is little or no difference unless you are logging a large amount of entries: in that case it is probably better to use the non-static version.

Hope it helps.